# Filtering a dataset by date and time Oracle SQL through Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi

I'm having trouble with filtering a date and time for anything two hours before and sooner. I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   table
where
   date >= sysdate - 1
AND
   TO_DATE( Time, 'HH24:MI:SS' ) >= TO_DATE( sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS' ) - 2
```

But I'm getting an inconsistent type error which is what I thought I was handling with the TO_DATE() function but I guess not.

Comment: there no time datatype in oracle. what is your expected result?

Comment: all records that exist based on the date and time right now and everything going back 2 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sysdate` is already a date (and time), so `TO_DATE( sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS' )` doesn't make any sense.

You didn't provide your data types for your `date` and `time` columns in `table`, so I'm going to assume they're both `varchar2(10)` with formats MM/DD/YYYY and HH24:MI:SS respectively.

I'm also going to go ahead and change your example table and column names, since they're invalid names to use in a real query.

```
-- example data
with my_table as (select '06/13/2019' as date_column, '09:40:34' as time_column from dual)
-- your query
SELECT * 
FROM 
   my_table
where
   to_date(date_column || ' ' || time_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= sysdate - 2/24
```

What I'm doing here is to combine your date and time strings into one date-time string, then converting it to an Oracle `date` type (actually date+time). Then we compare it to `sysdate - 2/24`, which says to take the current time and subtract 2/24ths of a day, which is 2 hours.

For this example, you might need to change the example data `date_column` and `time_column` values to something from the past 2 hours, depending on when you run this and what time zone you're in.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same error as before: DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Inconsistente types (7481)

Comment: I believe the time field is in a text format so it might have to be converted to a time before being applied? Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, if you look above, the format string in `to_date` converts both columns from text to date/time. Oh, that error sounds like your database is actually Progress OpenEdge db, it seems to handle type conversion differently than Oracle. I can't troubleshoot that for you, but probably if you try a few different ways you can figure out how to get the error to stop. https://knowledgebase.progress.com/?l=en_US&pn=1#q=7481&sort=relevancy

Comment: Thanks for the response @kfinity Seems I was steered in the wrong direction as far as oracle is concerned.